# Does the use of indexedDb on firefox-os devices require special permissions

Tags: firefox-os

My todo app using indexedDB works fine when running in the Firefox browser (v31 on Mac OSX 10.9.4). When I install it in the App manager and run it on the simulator (v1.2) the database doesn't open. The same happens on my Flame phone. Do I need to set any particular permissions beyond listing it in the manifest.webapp?

Comment: Is the application packaged or hosted?

Comment: If it's a packaged app, there shouldn't be a need for permissions at all. You should use the debugger to find out what doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the debugger isn't helpful. All I get is DOMError when I use console.log(request.error), not what DOMError it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out. Oddly, it had nothing to do with indexedDB at all. I have a routine that creates sample data to populate the database. One of those routines had an error. When writing the result to the database, it created an Abort error in the database. Thanks for your encouragement to use the debugger Loïc. It took me a while but I got there.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it shouldn't. But if you make big use of the indexeddb, you should add the `storage` permission which removes the limit in size of the database.

Here's a bigger list of permissions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions

> permission: storage
>   api: Storage
>   description: Utilize storage (appcache, pinned apps, IndexedDB) without size limitations. See appcache, IndexedDB.

Comment: According to the documentation it should be alright.

Comment: I've done that:
`code`"permissions": {"storage":{"description": "..."}}`code`